# Sponsorship Letter for UK Student Visa

Tags: uk

I am new to this and have never had to write a sponsorship letter before.  In doing so, what are the implications of such a letter?  What financial liabilities would I be in risk for secondary to whatever may happen while that person whom I am sponsoring is in country?  And how would the UK enforce it?

Comment: Welcome, David: since your profile indicates you're in the US, not the UK, would your sponsorship be financial? A sponsor may offer money and/or accommodation but is not liable for the actions of the visa holder. A visa applicant has to demonstrate their own eligibility and, in some cases, needing a sponsor can weaken an application. Could you say how this person is related to you (family, friend etc.)?

Comment: Sponsorship would be financial.  Relationship is daughter's fiance.

Comment: If it is a gift, not a loan, you would have to [submit your bank statements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/), evidence that certain funds are for his exclusive use, or transfer the money to him, or pay his fees.

Comment: I'm not clear, or certain, that a sponsorship letter is required: that usually comes from someone in the UK. I'm looking for the correct reference. If you are giving him money, that is different, and requires you documenting the gift. If he's applying for a Tier 4 student visa, he may be misunderstanding *sponsor* which is the UK institution, not an individual. Can you clarify the context?